# Regarding the logic on the meaning of negating "for all" to be there exists, can there exist then entail for all?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I think the title describes the question clearly.

When I think of something being negated, I think of that something to have the property that it can't happen anymore.

Maybe the error is in my understanding of negation?

Comment: The negation of "for all $x$... some property holds" is:  "there exists at least one $x$ for which the property does not hold."

Comment: Please don't rely on the title for the statement of your question. The body of your question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "there exists" does not **entail** "for all". Entailment means that the second must be true in *every* structure in which the first one is true, and obviously there can be situations where "there is an x P(x)" is true but "for all x P(x)" is not.

However, "there exists" is **consistent** with "for all", that is, it is not contradictory for them to be true at the same time. So if "not for all x P(x)", which is equivalent to "there exists an x not P(x)", it may also be the case (but is not entailed) that even "for all x not P(x)", i.e. "there exists no x P(x)".